# Sikuli - Click on element does not work with Java API but it works from IDE - WPF app

Tags: java, automated-tests, sikuli

I am evaluating tools for testing a WPF based app. I am currently trying Sikuli with the Java API. When I try to click on an object from Java code, the mouse cursor goes to the object and the object is highlighted, however the click action does not work, because the expected menu does not open. The click() method returns status 1 though.
If I am doing a click from Sikuli IDE, it works fine.
I tried 1.0.1 version and also the nightly build. Here's my code:

```
@Test
     public void testLogin() {
             Screen s = new Screen();
                try {
                        s.wait(Constants.overflowMenu);
                        System.out.println(s.click(Constants.overflowMenu));
                        s.wait(Constants.signInMenuOption, 5);
                } catch (FindFailed e) {
                        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
                }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try this code, it worked for me. what it does, it checks the image, click on it and then check this image again on the screen, if it still exists, click again.

Screen screen = new Screen();
        Pattern pattern = null;

```
    try
    {
        pattern = new Pattern(imageLocation);
        screen.wait(pattern,30);
        screen.click(pattern);
        System.out.println("First Attempt To Find Image.");
    }
    catch(FindFailed f)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception In First Attempt: " +f.getMessage());
        System.out.println("FindFailed Exception Handled By Method: ClickObjectUsingSikuli. Please check image being used to identify the webelement. supplied image: " +imageLocation);
        Assert.fail("Image wasn't found. Please use correct image.");
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //In case image/object wasn't clicked in first attempt and cursor stays in the same screen, then do second atempt.
    if(screen.exists(pattern) != null)
    {
        try
        {
            screen.getLastMatch().click(pattern);
            System.out.println("Second Attempt To Find Image.");
            System.out.println("Object: " +imageLocation + " is clicked successfully.");
        }
        catch(FindFailed f)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception In Second Attempt: " +f.getMessage());
            System.out.println("FindFailed Exception Handled By Method: ClickObjectUsingSikuli. Please check image being used to identify the webelement. supplied image: " +imageLocation);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seems it was a problem with the fact that I have two monitors..